# Powershell script not firing Register-ObjectEvent

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the below script for folder watcher:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exports\"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { 
                start-process C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exports\services\execute.bat
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 1}
```

The above script monitors  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exports\ folder and if there is any change to this folder, the $action is called. This script is not working and I see "Not started" error as below:

[image]

Any help on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think its a "feature", the `$action` script should fire. It only seems to enter `Running` state after the first event has been fired.

Temporarily insert below before `while ($true) {sleep 1}` and you should see the state change:

```
    Get-Job
    Set-Content -Path "$($watcher.Path)\a_test_file.txt" -Value "hello"
    Get-Job
```

(And for the sake of completeness `Get-Job -Id 1 | Stop-Job -PassThru | remove-Job` to stop and remove job id #1 - change id as required)